# custom MYSQL select query in WORDPRESS

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm creating a Wordpress site. I have a SQL table (wp_postmeta) with additional informations: dates and times for home and away mathes. (plugin ACF).
Table row are like this:

```
meta_id   post_id  meta_key        meta_value
1         123      home_0_date     20130512
2         123      home_1_date     20130513
3         123      home_0_time     13h
4         123      home_1_time     16h
5         123      away_0_date     20130514
6         123      away_1_date     20130515
7         123      away _0_time    18h
8         123      away _1_time    19h
```

There is a corrispondence betweet home_n_date and home_n_time and between away_n_date and away_n_time.
In fact in this case I'm adding two home matches: 12 / 05 / 2013 13h and  13 / 05 / 2013 16h
and two away matches 14/ 05 / 2013 18h and 15/ 05 / 2013 19h .

For a custom calendar I've this custom MYSQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_postmeta as pmd 
JOIN wp_posts as ps ON ps.ID = pmd.post_id 
WHERE (pmd.meta_key LIKE 'away_%_date' || pmd.meta_key LIKE 'home_%_date') 
&& ps.post_status = 'publish';
```

This works fine but in this case I'm selecting only dates without time with no distinction between home and away matches.
Now I want to add times and a way to differentiate home and away matches (adding some variables?)

```
"SELECT * 
FROM wp_postmeta as pmd 
JOIN wp_posts as ps ON ps.ID = pmd.post_id
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as pmt  ON ps.ID = pmt.post_id 
WHERE (pmd.meta_key LIKE 'away_%_date' || pmd.meta_key LIKE 'home_%_date') 
&& (pmt.meta_key LIKE 'away_%_time' || pmt.meta_key LIKE 'home_%_time') 
&&  (% = % /*???*/) 
&& ps.post_status = 'publish';
```

Any idea?

Comment: You really should be creating your own table, instead of trying to stuff this into postmeta.

Comment: I should. But I can't because I use these informations in other places. Thanks for reading and answering.

Comment: There's no need for another table here at all.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? why the need of a custom query? can't you work with wordpress functions like get_post_meta and get_posts? if not, why?